# CSS, Omega theme - how to make a <li> use 2 or 3 grids depending on screen with?

Tags: theming

This question applies to Omega theme, but I think it is general to any responsive grid based theme.

Is there a method to make a `<li>` occupy either 2 or 3 grids, depending on screen width?

In other words, when the body tag has class `responsive-layout-wide` then the `<li>` should occupy 3 grids (as if it had omega class `grid-3`) and when the body has class `responsive-layout-normal` it should occupy 2 grids (as if it had omega class `grid-2`). (The body class is determined using media queries by Omega theme)

Currently the HTML looks like this:

```
<li class="mydiv grid-2-normal grid-3-wide"> </li>
```

At design time I don't know the screen width, so I applied both possible classes. So currently, despite of the screen width, the `<li>` width is always 3 grids because `grid-3` is added last. Does Omega have any tools to make it dynamic?

The origin of this question lays here: http://drupal.org/node/1571938, unfortunately it is not explained to the end. The Views Columns Class module says:

> So you can apply alpha to the 1st, 5th, 9th blocks and omega to the
>   4th, 8th, 12th blocks but also apply alpha-mobile to the 1st, 3rd, 5th
>   blocks and omega-mobile on the 2nd, 4th, 6th blocks. **This gives the
>   freedom to the theme to apply the styles that would render a display
>   of 2 columns for smaller screen resolutions and 4 columns for larger
>   screen resolutions.**

So, I will end up having multiple styles for a `<li>` (like e.g. `grid-2-normal` and `grid-3-wide`) and my theme is supposed to react to screen width and intelligently apply appropriate style to change the `<li>` width. Width measured in grids (columns), not in pixels. But how this can be achieved, how to *render a display of 2 columns for smaller screen resolutions and 4 columns for larger screen resolutions*? Where "display" means a view display, not the whole page layout (that's what I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) can do this out of the box, but I don't think so.  Some base themes that use the grid system can change a size based on whether a column next to it is empty, but this isn't one of those conditions.

Your best option is to use the `grid-2` size in the config for that region, and then if you want it to be different, put an override for `mydiv` in one of the sheets that get enabled by the media queries (narrow, normal, or wide).  In your case you would add something like

```
.mydiv { width: 280px; }
```

to yourtheme-alpha-default-wide.css  The actual width will vary based on whether you are using 12, 16, or 24 columns, and you may need an `!important`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Taken for the theme's page:

Omega allows for contextual layouts (different layouts/settings for various portions of a site) through integration with [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) and the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.

Never done it myself to guide you but I believe what you want can be achieved by using these 2 modules. The documentation is always the best way to start.

Comment: Yes, these modules are good for changing layout of the whole page, but I'll check them from my problem point of view. I just hoped for something smaller. Maybe there isn't anything smaller. I will add a little more explanation at the end of the question.